# Long-term effects of antihistamines on mind and CNS

Tags: psychology, central-nervous-system, histamine, antihistamines

Can maybe someone share knowledge or guesses on the following questions:

1. Does the prolonged use of antihistamines cause long-term effects on mind or CNS?
2. Are there any known evidences of their influence of formation of CNS or personality when taken at a young age?
3. Generation-II antihistamines are said to be next to devoid of sedative effects since they selectively block just the H1-receptors. However, they are reportedly potentially mind-altering. How is this possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really a biology question

Comment: @GriffinEvo: can you suggest a more suitable stack exchange site? I have not found a site on biochemistry or anything more suitable...?

Comment: Not really - it's medical and there's no stack exchange site for that. I know it's not personal medical advice,  but it's not really a question of biology either

Comment: @GriffinEvo: yes, well, I agree.. sad but discussion on "medical" SE site has faded out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229495/stack-exchange-website-for-medical-questions ... well, maybe it is possible to move this question to http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/ ? does it seem more appropriate?

Comment: I think a medical SE is untenable because it generates a lot of risks - the people answering questions and offering medical advice aren't necessarily medical professionals, there's a lot of people out there looking to take advantage of those in need and a lot of people offering incorrect advice (with good intention) which might prevent someone from getting the correct treatment.

Comment: @GriffinEvo: what do you think about moving this question to cogsci SE site? If you think this could be done, then how can I do this?

Comment: I think the Mods have to do migrations - @kmm ?

Comment: @GriffinEvo: also, maybe you could propose a more appropriate site (not an SE site) to ask this? I am not into biosciences myself, so I do not know that segment of internet very well, but maybe you have some clue... I would really appreciate an advice since the question is important to me and is persisting in me for several years already.

Comment: These questions are ok for me but cannot answer them at the moment. Voted to reopen. However, very big chunk here and too much side tracked. You could reformulate your questions since the pharmacological sides of antihistamines are well known. All antihistamines pass BBB (1st gen most, 2nd gen less while 3rd gen very very little because antimetabolite of 2nd gen). These are Pharmacodynamic! Histamine can be released from all tissues ("hist"). So the drug primarily affects in all your tissues. Long-term effects have not been studied in no standardised situation. Immunosuppressed case neither.

Comment: I think you should split this question to many separate questions and then provide links between them: Ph.dyn antihistamines, their penetration of BBB and Pharmacology; long-term study about Ph.dyn antihistamine (take 2nd gen etc cetirizine) and Epidemiology in some standardised setting; same long-term study with some immunosuppressed patients; effect of 2nd gen antihistamines on cognition ... (think some parameter); etc. Personal medical advices are not provided in this site, since there are so many factors which we cannot consider publicly here and many other reasons too.

Comment: @GriffinEvo cogsci says it's off topic there too because of the personal medical orientation. I think it would be fine here or there (1) as separate questions and (2) as more general scientific questions as opposed to personal experience.

Comment: I edited and removed any personal info and basically stripped it down to a few sentences. The questions, however, are very broad and it may now be nominated for re-closure, if re-opened, but I think it deserves a chance.

Comment: And actually, the nature of the question may make it suitable for Cognitive Sciences SE. Specifically, question 2 could be deleted here and re-posted on Cognitive Sciences SE? This would kind of narrow down the question here as well.

Comment: Good edits so far, some comments though: The third questions suits Skeptics SE better (and if you insist on posting it here I want a source for "However, they are reportedly potentially mind-altering." and it should be a second separate post). The first and second are ok questions for here but may be better served by splitting in to two separate posts.